# uitableview still show VerticalScrollIndicator when dragging finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created a view as drawer. It contains a UITableview. When i drag UITableview down, the view will swipedown and the UITableview's contentoffset.y still be 0;
I changed UITableview frame in scrollViewDidScroll and scrollViewDidEndDragging, and after the animation UITableview seems like still be dragging that if i click the UITableview won't cause cell selected but VerticalScrollIndicator hide, after that UITableview return normal.

```
- (void)moveWithOffset:(CGFloat)offset {

CGFloat searchBarTop = _searchBar.top;
    self.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT-NavBar_HEIGHT;
    if (offset > 0) {
        if (GestureViewHeight - _searchBar.top > 0.1) {
            _gestureView.hidden = YES;
            searchBarTop = (_searchBar.top+offset) < GestureViewHeight ? (_searchBar.top+offset) : GestureViewHeight;
        } else {
            _gestureView.hidden = NO;
            if (self.top < SCREEN_HEIGHT/2) {
                self.top = (self.top+offset) < SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 ? (self.top+offset) : SCREEN_HEIGHT/2;
            }
        }
    } else if (offset < 0) {
        if (self.top - NavBar_HEIGHT > 0.1) {
            _gestureView.hidden = NO;
            self.top = (self.top+offset) > 64 ? (self.top+offset) : 64;
            searchBarTop = GestureViewHeight;
        } else {
            _gestureView.hidden = YES;
            if (searchBarTop > 0) {
                searchBarTop = (_searchBar.top+offset) > 0 ? (_searchBar.top+offset) : 0;
            }
        }
    }

[self adjustLayoutWithSearchBarTop:searchBarTop];
```

}

```
- (void)endMoving {
if ((int)self.top == NavBar_HEIGHT) {
    _state = ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateUp;
} else if ((int)self.top == SCREEN_HEIGHT*2/3) {
    _state = ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateMiddle;
} else if ((int)self.top == SCREEN_HEIGHT/2) {
    _state = ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateDown;
} else {
    if (self.top < SCREEN_HEIGHT/3 && _state != ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateUp) {
        _state = ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateUp;
    } else if (self.top > SCREEN_HEIGHT/3 && _state != ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateDown) {
        _state = ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateDown;
    } else {
        _state = ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateMiddle;
    }
}
[self animatingToState:_state];
```

}

```
- (void)animatingToState:(ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewState)state {
switch (state) {
    case ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateUp:
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, NavBar_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT-NavBar_HEIGHT);
            _gestureView.hidden = YES;
            [self adjustLayoutWithSearchBarTop:0];
        }];
    }
        break;
    case ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateDown:
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
            _gestureView.hidden = NO;
            [self adjustLayoutWithSearchBarTop:GestureViewHeight];
        }];
    }
        break;
    case ALDHotScenicSpotSearchViewStateMiddle:
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT/3, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT*2/3);
            _gestureView.hidden = NO;
            [self adjustLayoutWithSearchBarTop:GestureViewHeight];
        }];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

```
- (void)adjustLayoutWithSearchBarTop:(CGFloat)top {
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.top, self.width, SCREEN_HEIGHT-self.top);
_searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, top, self.width, 44);
_tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, _searchBar.bottom, self.width, self.height-_searchBar.bottom);
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
if (_isSwiping) {
    _isSwiping = NO;
    [self endMoving];

}
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && !scrollView.isDecelerating && (int)_searchBar.top == 0) {
    _isSwiping = YES;
}
if (_isSwiping) {
    [self moveWithOffset:-scrollView.contentOffset.y];
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: this only happen when i drag down the tableview fast, when drag down slowly it works fine

Answer (score 0):

[_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1) animated:YES];
[_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
add to function adjustLayoutWithSearchBarTop will resolve the problem. the reasom maybe scrollview.isdragging stay true in scrollViewDidEndDragging.